# How to click on a button within a specific div based on button text?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In a Cypress test, I am trying to click a specific button nested inside a div, based on it's text.

Below is the HTML code I am testing:

```html
<div class="mat-menu-content">
    <button>First button</button>
    <button>Second button</button>
</div>
```

I want to click the button with the `Second button` text.

I can't just use `cy.contains('Second button')` because `Second Button` text appears multiple places on the page.

Here's what I'm trying to write using Cypress:

- Click the button inside `mat-menu-content` div that contains `Second button` text

Can someone please tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple menus on the page, the item buttons are only displayed when the menu is open, and only one menu will be open at a time.

You can go ahead and just select the button with the text `Second button` after opening it's menu.

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Contacts Menu').click()  // open the menu
cy.contains('button', 'Second button').click()  // select 2nd item
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first grab the element by class name and then search for contents, and finally invoke the click() method. Try something like this:

```js
cy.get('.mat-menu-content').contains('Second button').click()
```

For more info, look here in the [official doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Usage)

Answer (score 1):

`.contains()` is quite powerful and allows the use of a selector paired with text, [`cy.contains('selector', 'Your text')`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Selector).

For your scenario, you'll want to use the `button` selector paired with the text to get the button containing `Second button`.

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Second button')

// or if there are multiple buttons with 'Second button' text on the page

cy.get('.mat-menu-content')
  .contains('button', 'Second button')
```

`.contains()` also allows for [regex matching](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Regular-Expression), which I prefer for finding with case insenstive.

```js
cy.contains('button', /second button/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variation, add `.mat-menu-content` ahead of the `button` selector

```js
cy.contains('.mat-menu-content button', 'Second button')  // tighter criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `mat-menu-content` on the webpage you can use `eq` to access a particular one and then use `within()` to scope your query within `div.mat-menu-content`

```js
cy.get('mat-menu-content')
  .eq(0)
  .within(() => {
    //eq(0) points to the first occurance in the DOM
    cy.contains('button', 'Second button').click()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to do 'Click the button inside mat-menu-content div that contains Second button text' i suggest

`cy.get('div.mat-menu-content button').contains('Second button').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single `get` command that satisfies exactly what you want to do:

`cy.get('div.mat-menu-content button:contains("Second button")'`